# how to join tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables created using phpmyadmin.

`Tables - students{s_id,name,address,phone no,branch}`

and

`events{s_id,event_id,event_name,date,time,venue}.`

how to get names of event registered by each student?
how to write this query in CodeIgniter?

Comment: Have a look on here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html /query_builder.html scroll down and look for `$this->db->join()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this with a function and you can return the variable also for further purpose from the model.

If you use function you have to use `return $query->result();` at the last line of the function that you write.

But the basic structure is that how i have mentioned below.

```
$this->db->select('students.*,events.*');
$this->db->from('students');
$this->db->join('events', 'students.sid = events.event_id', 'left'); 
$query = $this->db->get();// This will retrieve all the fields after joining
```

Functional Method:

```
function getAllResults()
{
$this->db->select('students.*,events.*');
$this->db->from('students');
$this->db->join('events', 'students.sid = events.event_id', 'left'); 
$query = $this->db->get();// This will retrieve all the fields after joining
return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: @Sanket Deshpande Have you obtained the desired output:)

Comment: @SanketDeshpande. Welcome. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I just give you a hint so you can solve by yourself:

```
function yourFunction(){
  $this->db->select('students.*,events.*');
  $this->db->from('students');
  $this->db->join('events', 'students.sid = events.event_id', 'left'); 
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}
```

For further knowledge go [THERE](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html):

Comment: don't for get this part `$query = $this->db->get();` after join